# Docusign Integration with Android/Ios Application

Tags: android, ios, api, docusignapi

I have a software product & want to integrate the docusign into it. I went through the docusign features & was really impressed.

Please provide details on below mentioned points;

1. What all i need to integrate the docusign into my application (mobile - android/ios) ?
2. Application consists of various functional modules, i want the document to be sent for signature from the application using the docusign. How this can be done?
3. Does all my clients need account of docusign for signing the document ?
4. Clarify whether Docusign allows for working on a document received from a web-service call, If yes then how the status of a document can be maintained (completed, Canceled etc.) ?

Answer (score 0):

Aryan, you might want to start with www.docusign.com/devcenter - it has a few starting guides that might help you.

You will see how to send a document through DocuSign API right in the beginning. You might also want to take advantage of the pre-build java client library: www.github.com/docusign

The signers do not need an account to sign.

There is a notification service called "DocuSign Connect" that will push events, status and data for you: https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/connect

Hope this helps!  Thanks for choosing DocuSign!